# What do I need to get Word Automation Services?

Tags: licensing

As I understand it, Word Automation Services is a part of SharePoint 2010. But what Version of SharePoint 2010 do I need to use it? Is SharePoint Foundation enough? Or SharePoint Server or do I even need the Enterprise Edition or something?

It would be great if you could link to your source of information in your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Word Automation Services is not part of Office Web Apps nor part of SharePoint Foundation. It is a feature of SharePoint Server 2010 for which you must have to purchase and install SharePoint Server 2010 to use Word Automation Services.

Check this link out [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558278.aspx/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are missing a "not" before "part of SharePoint Foundation" ...

Comment: Is there any way to enable word automation feature in Sharepoint Foundation?

Answer (score 1):

I know it isn't available in Foundations, I believe the office web apps are Enterprise only.

Comment: Ok, it isn't available in the Foundation. But does it belong to the Office Web Applications?

Comment: I was mashing Word Automation in with Office Web Apps, Paul's answer is the one to go with.